# move object properties in array

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  condition: 'checked' // could be "unckecked" or anything else
  items: []
}
```

and I want to check if the `condition === checked` then I will have to move `a` and `b` inside items like this:

```
const obj = {
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  condition: 'checked' // could be "unckecked" or anything else
  items: [{
       a: 1,
       b: 2,
  }]
}
```

I have tried splice and tried to loop through the object with `for(of)` but didn't manage to do it, any idea how?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. **What have you tried?** Hint: [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) or create a new object and populate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @todman I have tried that but I tried to avoid the delete actually, is there any other way?

Comment: check `if( obj.condition === 'checked' )`  and append the values to `obj.items`?

Comment: @Errand you want to push a and b or push the first and the second property? I mean a always called a and b always called b in any case?

Comment: I want to push a and b and I have specific values and not random values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `delete`, you can use a function to return a new object instead with the values moved as required:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  condition: 'checked', // could be "unckecked" or anything else
  items: []
}

const moveit = ({ a, b, condition, items, ...rest}) => 
condition === 'checked' ? { ...rest, condition, items: [{ a, b }] } : { a, b, ...rest, condition, items };

console.log(moveit(obj))
```

Comment: that would do the job! nice one :)

Comment: @Errand I'm glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want delete, try a reduce

You could make this a little more DRY if you mapped the keys to the item

```js
let  obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, condition: 'checked',  items: [] };

if (obj.condition ==="checked") {
  const keys = ["a","b"]
  obj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc,[key,val]) => {
    if (key === "items") acc[key] = [{ a:obj.a,  b:obj.b}];
    else if (!keys.includes(key)) acc[key] = val;
    return acc;
  },{})
}  

console.log(obj)
```

Older answer:

```js
let  obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, condition: 'checked',  items: [] };

if (obj.condition ==="checked") {
  obj.items.push({ a:obj.a,  b:obj.b})
  delete obj.a;
  delete obj.b;
}  

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  condition: 'checked',
  items: []
};

// If condition equals 'checked'
if (obj.condition === 'checked') {
    
    // Move a and b into items
    obj.items.push({ 
      a: obj.a,
      b: obj.b
    });
    
    // Delete old key/values
    delete obj.a;
    delete obj.b;
}

// Show result
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have tried this one but is there a way without delete?

Comment: You'll need `delete` to remove the old `a` and `b`. key from obj

Comment: but is there a way where I can move them and not really delete after pushing to the array?

Comment: So `obj.a` and `obj.b` should stay intact? Just remove the `delete` call

Comment: Please update your question with the desired output, currently it's showing a new object without `obj.a` and `obj.b`

Comment: I want to move them inside items and dont keep them as a direct properties of obj, and I think the question is clear, no?